# How to call a non-static method from a static function in a class in php

Tags: php, function, oop

My code is like below:

```
<?php

    class ClassName {
        private $data = null;
            public function __construct($data) {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
        public static function staticFun ($data) {
            echo $this->anotherFun($data);
        }
        private function anotherFun ($data) {
            return $this->data;
        }
    }

?>
```

I am trying to call `ClassName::staticFun('nilya');` as `staticFun` is a static function but I get `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` error. I know the distinction between static and non-static methods and how to call them but, in above code the given error occurs.

Is it possible to call a non-static method in a static method? If not how should the code be modified to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `$this` with something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an instance:

```
    public static function staticFun ($data) {
        $instance = new ClassName($data);
        echo $instance->anotherFun($data);
    }
```

Note: you have a parameter `$data` for `anotherFun`, but you don't use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bellow Code You can call another function from static function.

In Static method $this Not Working So First we create Object of current Class.

`

```
class ClassName {
        private $data = null;
        public function __construct($data) {
            $this->data = $data;
        }
        public static function staticFun ($data) {
            $call = new ClassName($data);
            $value = $call->anotherFun($data);
            return $value;
        }
        private function anotherFun ($data) {
            return $this->data;
        }
}

$obj = new ClassName("vajram");
$valueget = $obj->staticFun("phaneendra");
echo $valueget;
```

?>`